# i cant find the user profile page in asp.net webapp

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, identity

i was following microsoft's tutorial for identity auth via this link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

after i have finished i wanted to visit the code of the profile page . and i couldnt find it anywhere

i looked at the account folder and the pages folder ..

Comment: Did the following reply help you? If you need further help, you can leave a message to let me know.

Comment: that helped but i want to know how can i customize the user table

Comment: also how can i leave you a message here xD

Comment: Generally speaking, a good post should only contain one question, so that more professional help can be obtained.

Comment: The other problem you just mentioned may not be my specialty, you can create a new post to ask for help. In the current post, the general community members rarely follow up on this issue after seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the official doc and test in my local. I also can't find the profile page, but I know the reason, these pages are integrated into the identity.

We can add Scaffold Identity into the project, then we can find the pages you want.

---

**.Net 6**

[.Net6 - Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design -Version 6.0.10
```

---

**.Net 7**

[.Net7 - Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

---

**Test Result**

[image]